# fluent ffmpeg how to take a screenshot from a stream and save it onto a stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have the following code

```
ffmpeg(readStream)
  .setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
  .outputOptions('-vframes 1')
  .outputOptions('-f image2pipe')
  .outputOptions('-vcodec png')
  .writeToStream(writeStream)
```

Which runs fine without any errors, but it does not store the screenshot in the output stream.

What I'm doing wrong? It looks like I'm now waiting for the process to finish, but if so, how can I wait?

Answer (score 1):

For me this setup works:

```js
        ffmpeg(input, {
            timeout: 60,
            logger: this.logger,
        })
            .seek(1)
            .format('image2pipe')
            .outputOptions(['-f image2pipe', '-vframes 1'])
            .on('start', command => {
                /**
                 * log
                 */
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                /**
                 * log
                 */
            })
            .on('error', (err, _, stderr) => {
                /**
                 * log
                 */
            })
            .pipe(output, { end: true });
```

> **input** is Readable (or PassThrough), **output** is Writable (or PassThrough)

Also this given setup won't work with all video formats. For me it does for the following mimetypes:

video/mp4
video/webm
video/ogg
audio/ogg
video/x-ms-wmv
video/mpeg
video/x-msvideo